# extension properties displayed in graph but not in powershell

Tags: powershell, graph

i have synced an extension "departmentnumber" to azure ad.
I can see the output in ms graph, when i do the following: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/*************************?$select=extension_450c0e26a8a440748e1e4f*******_departmentNumber`

The problem is, that I can not see it in powershell. There is only a blank field as you can see here:

[image]

As I understood it, there should be another row with this output: `extension_450c0e26a8a440748e1e4f*******_departmentNumber`

Where is my mistake?

purpose: i want to get an export, where every user is listed with the assigned licences and the departmentnumber which will get added in onprem AD. If anyone has a better solution - please tell me

Thx for yourt help guys!! :)

Comment: [This example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/using-extension-attributes-sample?view=azureadps-2.0#retrieve-a-the-value-of-a-specific-extension-property-for-a-user) seems to indicate you should be able to do `(Get-AzureADExtension -ObjectID ...).get_Item('extension_450c0e26a8a440748e1e4f*******_departmentNumber')` - does that give you anything?

Comment: The output fails with the following message: the given key was not present in the dictionary

I do not unterstand what that means..also not after googling about..

Thx for your help!